# Retrieve first element value using XMLReader C#

Tags: c#, xml-parsing, xmlreader

I am currently developing an app to parse multiple XML files. I have used both `XmlDocument` and `XmlReader`. Here is one of the parts.

```
 private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var filenames = System.IO.Directory
                       .EnumerateFiles(textBox1.Text, "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                       .Select(System.IO.Path.GetFullPath);

        foreach (var f in filenames)
        {
            var sr = new MyStreamReader(f);
            var resolver = new XmlUrlOverrideResolver();
            resolver.DtdFileMap[@"XSEIF_R6.DTD"] = @"\\loc\XSEIF_R6.DTD";
            resolver.DtdFileMap[@"XSEIF_R5.DTD"] = @"\\loc\XSEIF_R5.DTD";
            resolver.DtdFileMap[@"XSEIF R5.DTD"] = @"\\loc\XSEIF_R5.DTD";

            XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse;
            settings.XmlResolver = resolver;
            XmlReader doc = XmlReader.Create(sr, settings);

            while (doc.Read())
            {
                if ((doc.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (doc.Name == "var"))
                {
                    if (newdoc.HasAttributes)
                    {
                        String vname = newdoc.GetAttribute("name");
                        String vno = newdoc.GetAttribute("number");
                        String pname = newdoc.GetAttribute("p-names");

                        File.AppendAllText(@"loca\Var.txt", vname + pname + Environment.NewLine);
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
        MessageBox.Show("Done");
    }
```

There is no problem with the code. Now I want to add another output. I need to add the value of another tag named "title". The tag has multiple occurrences. But I need only the first occurrence.  I know how to do it in `XmlDocument` but as I did this earlier using `XmlReader`, i want to continue that.

How to get the value of the first title tag?

Comment: You can use linq to xml pretty easily: `XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(string); XElement root = doc.Root; XElement wantedElement = root.Elements("title").First();`

Comment: @CalebB OP wants to know how to do using XmlReader, so you would use `XDocument.Load(reader)` instead of a string.

Comment: @JNYRanger You are correct, I was merely expressing an alternative. :)

Comment: @CalebB I'm with ya though, I'm a big fan of linq to xml, and avoid `XmlDocument` at all costs!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are familar with `XmlDocument` you should just use the `XmlReader` to [load](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8ta6tz4(v=vs.110).aspx) an `XmlDocument`

This can be done easily (assume the `XmlReader` is named reader):

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument;
doc.Load(reader);
//perform queries
```

The only catch with this is that you need to make sure that the `XmlReader` is currently in it's initial state since it's forward reading only and can produce unexpected results since it will load from the current location of the reader assuming that it's at the root node.

Also based on your posted code you should note that the MSDN Documentation recommends to **NOT** use the `GetElementsByTagName()` method.  Instead you should use [`SelectNodes()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcebdtae(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`SelectSingleNode()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb63z0tw(v=vs.110).aspx) which take an XPath expression to return a `XmlNodeList` or single `XmlNode` respectively.

**EDIT:**
*OP has modified his question & changed the posted code since it wasn't completely clear.  Here's the answer of the current iteration of the question using `XmlReader`:*

You need to understand that unlike other XML parsing in C# the `XmlReader` is forward reading only.  Therefore you cannot just add code to the end of your loop since you would need to re-read the entire document once again, which would be a waste.  I would recommend doing this with a flag and an additional `else if` statement so you can handle this all on the single read.  Here's an example:

```
bool notFound = true;
while (doc.Read())
{
    if ((doc.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (doc.Name.Equals("var")))
    {
        if (newdoc.HasAttributes)
        {
            String vname = newdoc.GetAttribute("name");
            String vno = newdoc.GetAttribute("number");
            String pname = newdoc.GetAttribute("p-names");

            //File.AppendAllText(@"loca\Var.txt", vname + pname + Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }
    else if(notFound && doc.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && doc.Name.Equals("title"))
    {
         notFound = false;
         //do whatever you need to do here w/ this node
    }
}
```

With this above example you will most likely need to move your write to the correct location once you have all the data that you need, which is why I commented it out.  Also notice that I changed your string comparisons to use `Equals` instead of `==`.  Never use `==` for string comparison.

Comment: Thanks for your response. 
XmlReader doc = XmlReader.Create(sr, settings);
                while (doc.Read())
                    {
                    if ((doc.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (doc.Name == "title"))
                        {
}
Now the problem is, if i write, doc.ReadInnerXML(), it retrives all the  text of all the title elements but i need only the first one. Thats where i was stuck

Comment: One step at a time.  First handle the reading.  Don't bother with any writes until you have the correct node.  My example is to show you how use your `XmlReader` in an `XmlDocument` since you said you were already familiar with that.  This comment is stating is a completely different question than your original post.

Comment: Additionally the loop in your example in your comment should break as soon as you enter the if statement's code block the first time otherwise you'll continue to read the document and enter the conditional code block.

Comment: Sorry. I am confused. I updated the code now. My requirement is i need to add a block of code to retrieve the first occurrence of the title tag with the XMLreader code itself. I dont want to load the XMLreader into XML doc. I want to continue in this way and do it.

Comment: @ShahulHameed Take a look now.

Comment: I know about the loop but my concern is regarding this line

(//do whatever you need to do here w/ this node). Like you have mentioned, i need to one operation and i dont know how. That is my concern. I need to retrieve the value of first title tag. so when  say doc.innerxml, it retireves all the values. how can i retrieve only the first value. thats what my concern. Thanks for your response

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73418/discussion-between-jnyranger-and-shahul-hameed).